# Handling array values using specific array element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an array value like this. I tried array_search and it is of no use. 
Just what I want is to filter only the array values that have status value.

## Output

```
    Array
    (
    [1] => Array
    (
    [author] => Author1
    [book] => Book1
    [status] => 1
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
    [author] => Author2
    [book] => Book2
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
    [author] => Author3
    [book] => Book3
    [status] => 1
    )
    )
```

## Expected Output

```
Array
    (
    [1] => Array
    (
    [author] => Author1
    [book] => Book1
    [status] => 1
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
    [author] => Author3
    [book] => Book3
    [status] => 1
    )
    )
```

I will be more happy if the expected output has the proper number sequence. In the above case there are two arrays with array number as [1] and [3] . If possible i need to make it as [1] and [2].

Any help will be very useful.

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

```
foreach($my_array as $arr) {
    if(isset($arr['status']) && $arr['status'] != '') {
        $temp_array[] = $arr;
    }
}
print_r($temp_array);
```

Comment: Gautam - someone down voted. don't know why. could you upvote my question ;) please. i have marked your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$array = array(['status' => 1], [], ['status' => 1]);

$result = array_filter($array, function($item)
    {
    return !empty($item['status']);
    });

var_dump($result);
```